# Are the factors of SUSY factorization the conjugate transpose of each other?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, supersymmetry

I am trying to learn about SUSY by reading [Freed Cooper, et al.](http://www.phy.pku.edu.cn/~qhcao/resources/class/QM/F.Cooper,etc.-Physics-Reports.pdf)

I understand that a Hamiltonian with ground state energy equal to $0$ ($E_0=0$).

$$ - \frac{\hbar^2}{2 m} \frac{d^2}{d x^2} \psi_0 + V_1(x) \psi_0(x) = 0 $$

Can be factorized into:

$$ H_1 = A^\dagger A $$

where

$$ A = \frac{\hbar}{\sqrt{2m}} \frac{d}{dx} + W(x) \quad ; \quad A^\dagger = - \frac{\hbar}{\sqrt{2m}} \frac{d}{dx} + W(x) \qquad (1)$$

Another Hamiltonian can be obtained by reversing the order of the operators:

$$ H_2 =  A A^\dagger$$

Then the eigenfunctions and eigenvalues of $H_1$ and $H_2$ are related by:

$$ H_1 \psi_n^1 = A^\dagger A \psi_n^1 = E_n^1 \psi_n^1 \rightarrow H_2 ( A \psi_n^1 ) = A A^\dagger A \psi_n^1 = E_n^1 ( A \psi_n^1 ) $$

And

$$ H_2 \psi_n^2 =  A A^\dagger \psi_n^2 = E_n^2 \psi_n^2  \rightarrow H_1 ( A^\dagger \psi_n^2 ) =  A^\dagger A  A^\dagger \psi_n^2 = E_n^2 ( A \psi_n^2 ) $$

(where the upper index is used to identify the Hamiltonian of the eigenfunctions)

These equations relate $\psi_{n+1}^1$ to $\psi^2_n$.

My question is if $A$ and $A^\dagger$ are the conjugate transpose of each other. If not, how could I calculate $< \psi_{n+1}^1 |$? In order to compute $< \psi_{n+1}^1 | H_1 |\psi_{n+1}^1 >  = E_{n+1}^1 $.

It makes sense because:

$$ E_n^2 = <\psi_n^2 | H_2 | \psi_n^2 > =  < \psi_{n+1}^1 A^\dagger | H_2 | A \psi_{n+1}^1 > $$

$$=< \psi_{n+1}^1 A^\dagger  AA^\dagger  A \psi_n^1 > =  < \psi_n^1 H_1 H_1 \psi_{n+1}^1 > = (E_n^1)^2  $$
 However, equation (1) doesn't seem to be the conjugate transpose.

Comment: FWIW: Yes, the operator $A^{\dagger}$ is the [Hermitian adjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint) of $A$.

Comment: Then, why on equation (1) the sign is reversed where no imaginary number exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the operator $A^{\dagger}$ is the [Hermitian adjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint) of $A$: Integration by parts of $\frac{d}{d x}$ causes a minus sign: 
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}}\!dx~ \phi^{\ast}(x)\frac{d}{d x} \psi(x)
~=~-\int_{\mathbb{R}}\!dx~ \psi(x)\frac{d}{d x} \phi^{\ast}(x) $$
up to boundary terms. (A similar argument yields that the [momentum operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum_operator) $\hat{p}=\frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{d}{d x}$ is Hermitian.)

Comment: Could you elaborate more on how the integration by parts causes the minus sign? I don’t really know where you need to integrate to obtain $A^\dagger$

Comment: I updated the answer.